# How can I compare two bson.M data sets using Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I have the following code which retrieves two data sets from two different collections in a MongoDB database

```
    opts := options.Find()
    opts.SetProjection(bson.M{
        "productId": 1,
        "_id": 0,
    })

    cursor, err := currentProductsCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{}, opts)
    var oldProducts []bson.M
    err = cursor.All(ctx, &oldProducts)

    cursor, err = newProductsCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{}, opts)
    var newProducts []bson.M
    err = cursor.All(ctx, &newProducts)
```

I want to be able to compare `oldProducts` with `newProducts` to find out what new productId's have appeared and which old productId's have disappeared.

The two variables have both loaded fine and I can happily inspect them in the debugger, but I can't seem to find a way of comparing them. I had hoped to be able to range over each in turn doing a lookup on the other and getting a couple of slices of missing values but I can't find any way to do it.

I've been going round the houses with this for the last three hours so if anyone has any suggestions I would more than welcome them.

I am using the vanilla [go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver](https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) drivers, not mgo

Comment: I'd like to thank both Burak and Eklavya for your solutions. I wish I could mark them both as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create map for both old product and new product by product id

```
oldProductsMap = make(map[interface{}]bson.M)
for _,oldp := range oldProducts {
   oldProductsMap[oldp["productId"]] = oldp
}

newProductsMap = make(map[interface{}]bson.M)
for _,newp :=range newProducts {
   newProductsMap[newp["productId"]] = newp
}
```

Then for the disappeared product check old product is in `newProductsMap`. If not then the product disappeared

```
var disProducts []bson.M
for _,oldp := range oldProducts {
   if _, ok := newProductsMap[oldp["productId"]]; !ok {
       disProducts = append(disProducts, oldp) 
   }
}
```

For newly appeared product check new product is in `oldProductsMap`. If not then the product newly appeared.

```
var appProducts []bson.M
for _,newp := range newProducts {
   if _, ok := oldProductsMap[newp["productId"]]; !ok {
       appProducts = append(appProducts, oldp)
   }
}
```

*Note* : *You can do this portion when create map for new product also*

Comment: this looks like it might be what I am looking for. I tried making a map but I was trying map[string]interface{} which didn't work. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Hmm,  cannot use oldp["productId"] (type interface {}) as type int in map index: need type assertion
And same message for newp.

Comment: You can use `map[interface{}]bson.M`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure all entries have the `productId` field:

```
func exists(in []bson.M,id interface{}) bool {
   for _,p:=range in {
     if id==p["productId"] {
        return true
     }
   }
  return false
}
```

Then use this to scan both lists:

```
for _,oldp:=range oldProducts {
   if !exists(newProducts,oldp["productId"]) {
     // Removed
   }
}

for _,newp:=range newProducts {
   if !exists(oldProducts,newp["productId"]) {
     // Added
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, definitely all entries have productId. I'll try your solution in the morning, Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Hmm, I get: "Invalid operation: id==in["productId"] (operator == is not defined on bson.M) "

Comment: It should've been p["productId"]. I fixed the answer